# How to define flask-sqlalchemy objects on demand?

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, runtime

I have a module which I want to use for handling database access to both the production and a test database.

The content looks like this:

```
class FirstModel(db.Model):
    #...
class SecondModel(db.Model):
    #...

def get_production_connection():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = PRODUCTION_DATABASE_URI
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    return db

def get_test_connection():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = TEST_DATABASE_URI
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    return db
```

Unfortunately this is not working since the defined models inherit from `db.Model` which is not defined obviously  when the classes are evaluated. Is there any way how I can make the classes/models to inherit from the db.Model class which is only accessible through the `db` object when one of the methods above is called?

Comment: Correct me if I got this wrong: You have an app running in production, and in certain times you'd like to access to production DB, and some times to test DB, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy, but perhaps you can inherit from SQLAlchemy.Model instead?

Comment: @cemkyg Sort of: I have some unit tests which should access the test database while the production code should access the production database. I could solve this problem by creating two modules one for production and one for tests within which I create a db object on initialization before all model definitions - but then I would have to define all models twice which is undesirable for me.

Comment: It seems as if there is no SQLAlchemy.Model - at least in the flask wrapped version I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it now via:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

#models here

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    #db configuration
    db.init_app(app)
    return db
```

as shown here http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy

Comment: That's correct. Can you accept the answer so this won't pop up in unanswered questions?

Comment: Thank you for the hint - accepting my own answer is still blocked for some hours.